# Visual Studio Code - Disabling check for updates in linux

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, debian, ubuntu-18.04

I have downloaded the .deb package for visual studio code 1.46 for Ubuntu 18.04 and I found there is a check for update option on launching the shortcut. Is there any way to disable the check for updates option in the .deb package?  I don't want to do it manually by going to the settings, so if anyone could tell me which file is responsible for check for updates, it would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it in the preferences, you can edit your global `settings.json` which is in your profile folder.

Add this line `"update.mode": "none"`

Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

Mac `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: Is there anyway to  modify the .deb package and add $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json  and then repack it ?

Comment: If not the above mentioned location Like $HOME/.config/Code/User  ( A user HOME directory) , is there an equivalent general location where i put the settings.json file and it will work as expected ?